# How to run multiple call with-in a function parallel

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a few functions that build a user response class and I am still grasping the TASK async await.

From the code below is there a way to run all the all in parallel rather than one at a time?

I guess my first question should be how is the call taking place the way it is set up now?

My second question is how can i run all these calls in parallel?

It is not necessary for the returns to return in any specific order

```
public static async Task<ProjectForDrawings> GetProjectInfo(string cnn, int projectID)
    {

        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ProjectForDrawings projectForDrawings = DataBase.proc_GetProject_ForDrawings.ToRecord<ProjectForDrawings>(cnn, projectID);

            projectForDrawings.Submittals = DataBase.proc_GetSubmittal.ToList(cnn, projectID);

            projectForDrawings.ProjectLeafs = DataBase.proc_GetProjectLeafs.ToList<ProjectLeaf>(cnn, projectID);

            projectForDrawings.Revisions = DataBase.proc_GetRevisionsForProject.ToList<Revisions>(cnn, projectID);

            return projectForDrawings;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is the call taking place the way it is set up now?

It schedules the work to a background thread (`Task.Run`) and then asynchronously waits for it to complete (`await`). The work will execute each database proc one at a time, synchronously blocking the background thread until it completes.

> how can i run all these calls in parallel?

You can start all the tasks, and then `await` them all with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public static async Task<ProjectForDrawings> GetProjectInfo(string cnn, int projectID)
{
  ProjectForDrawings projectForDrawings = DataBase.proc_GetProject_ForDrawings.ToRecord<ProjectForDrawings>(cnn, projectID);

  var submittalsTask = Task.Run(() => DataBase.proc_GetSubmittal.ToList(cnn, projectID));
  var leafsTask = Task.Run(() => DataBase.proc_GetProjectLeafs.ToList<ProjectLeaf>(cnn, projectID));
  var revisionsTask = Task.Run(() => DataBase.proc_GetRevisionsForProject.ToList<Revisions>(cnn, projectID));

  await Task.WhenAll(submittalsTask, leafsTask, revisionsTask);

  projectForDrawings.Submittals = await submittalsTask;
  projectForDrawings.ProjectLeafs = await leafsTask;
  projectForDrawings.Revisions = await revisionsTask;
  return projectForDrawings;
}
```

**However**, many (most?) databases do not allow multiple queries per database connection, so this may not work for your database. Also, it may not be a good idea to parallelize calls on the database in the first place - it is possible to cause a self-imposed denial-of-service. Finally, [using `Task.Run` in the implementation is not a good pattern](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) (for reasons I describe on my blog) - using natural async methods would be better.

Comment: In this article it is stating that 2005 and up for sql server there is a pool of connections and if a caller makes a call to the db on the same connection it will grab one of the available connections and use it. If there is no open connection it will throw a bunch of available connection to the caller to choose from. This is only loose talk here, and I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com: It depends on how the `DataBase` methods are implemented. If they're all using an independent `DbConnection`, then that should work. If they're all using the same `DbConnection` instance, then you'll see an exception.